# Fetching and Displaying data from multi-dimension array repeatedly in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, postgresql

I fetch the data from PostgresSQL server and put them into an array using:

```
var that = this;
var temp = [];
await fetch(req)
  .then(function(res) {
    res.json().then(function(data) {
      for (var i in data) {
        temp.push([
          data[i].flavor
          data[i].addons,
          data[i].price
        ]);
      }
      that.setState({
        thatArray: temp
      });
    });
  })

console.log(this.state.thatArray);
```

The result of `console.log(this.state.thatArray)` looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeXZ9.jpg

I want to display the data repeatedly until the end of the array in this form (Example image below)

```html
<div className="row-container">
  <div className="flavor-name">
    <div>Milk</div>
  </div>

  <div className="add-tab">Add</div>

  <div className="add-tab-list">
    <li>- Cereal</li>
    <li>- Red Jelly</li>
    <li>- Peach</li>
    <li>- Honey Star</li>
  </div>

  <div className="price-text" style={{ textAlign: "right", marginRight: "20px" }}>
    40 USD
  </div>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Example result: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqvIU.jpg)

I have used `array.map()` before, but with just a single array to do the list. It was very confusing when I tried to make it work with this kind of array.
Is there any simple way of displaying the data?

---

Edit: The rendering method suggested by Phix works beautifully. But I still have a problem with array.

Here is my `componentWillMount()` and`getProducts()`

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
       bag: getProducts()
    });
}

function getProducts() {
  let uid = {
    userID: localStorage.getItem("user")
  };

  var req = new Request("/user/order", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json"
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify(uid)
  });

  var temp = [];

  fetch(req)
    .then(function(res) {
      res.json().then(function(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
          temp.push([
            data[i].flavor,
            data[i].addons,
            data[i].price
          ]);
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

  console.log(temp);


  return temp;

  //return [
  //  ["Milk", ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"], "40"],
  //  ["Charcoal", ["Item 1a", "Item 2a", "Item 3a"], "45"],
  //  ["Ham", ["Item 1b", "Item 2b", "Item 3b"], "30"]
  //];
}
```

The problem is that it only works when I directly state the returned array.

```
return [
["Milk", ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"], "40"],
["Charcoal", ["Item 1a", "Item 2a", "Item 3a"], "45"],
["Ham", ["Item 1b", "Item 2b", "Item 3b"], "30"]
];
```

It doesn't work when I return the `temp` array. Nothing showed up on the screen.

```
return temp;
```

I noticed that the array are different.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Axw0.png

The first line in the picture of both arrays is not the same. The above one is the array from the fetched response and the bottom one is the manually typed one.

Edit: I found out that the console is `live` and the content was empty when first called, so the first line looks empty. But still, cannot figure out my problem.

Also, when returning `temp`, referencing `bag[0]` gives nothing and `bag[0][1]` will result in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined` while everything works perfectly when `getProducts()` return the manually typed array.

---

Edit: I tried doing `this.setState({ bag: this.state.bag });` on button click later after everything is loaded, and all the data appeared. Is there any way to make this happen since the page initially loaded?

Comment: Please include code as text, not as images, in a [mcve]. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make that easier.

Comment: edit: snippets added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's "tighter" ways, but here's one idea to hopefully get you started:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      bag: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      bag: getProducts()
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { bag } = this.state;

    const renderTitle = (index) => {
      return <h1>{bag[index][0]}</h1>
    }

    const renderItems = (index) => {
      const items = bag[index][1]
      return (
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
      )
    }

    const renderPrice = (index) => {
      return <div>{bag[index][2]}</div>
    }

    return (
      bag.map((group, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {renderTitle(index)}
            {renderItems(index)}
            {renderPrice(index)}
          </div>
        )
      })
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

function getProducts() {
  return [
    ['Milk', ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'], '40'],
    ['Charcoal', ['Item 1a', 'Item 2a', 'Item 3a'], '45'],
    ['Ham', ['Item 1b', 'Item 2b', 'Item 3b'], '30'],
  ]
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lhsugb)

**Edit**:

The reason `temp` is coming back like that is it's initially being seen as an empty array, but once the fetch resolves it will show what you're expecting.

```
var temp = [];            // [0] Start empty
fetch(req).then(() => {   // [1] Fire off async request and continue with event loop
  // ...                     [4] Once this resolves, temp gets populated
})
console.log(temp); //        [2] Event loop continues to here, showing empty array
return temp; //              [3] Nothing here
```

Or, with async/await:

```
var temp = [];                   // [0] Start empty
const results = await fetch(req);// [1] Wait for async request and continue
console.log(temp);
return temp;                        [2] As expected
```

I've updated the stackblitz with a faux request to render async data.

Comment: Thank you! this is brilliant. It really helps me displaying the data. I still have a problem fetching the array, can you look into the problem that I edited into the main post?

Comment: OMG, it works like charm. I can't thank you enough!